# PHP ImageMagick - Draw Indic text using font file, not from system fonts

Tags: php, fonts, imagemagick, pango, indic

I am trying to draw Devanagari text on image using PHP ImageMagick.
ImageMagick renders text correctly if I use font available in the system, but not when loading a font from a file.
For exmaple if use

`$imagick->setFont('Lohit Marathi');// installed font`

works correctly but if I use

`$imagick->setFont("fonts/lohit_mr.ttf");//load from file`

Font does not loads and it renders using default font.

code I am trying is as follows

```
<?php
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setFont('ANY_SYSTEM_FONT') // works; 
$imagick->setFont('somefont.ttf') // does not work;  
?>
```

Can someone point out anything I am missing?

Comment: Try to use all path like `$imagick->setFont("/www/web/imagicksample/fonts/alittlepot.ttf");`

Comment: I am on Windows so I used absolute path like D:/web_projects/test/myfont.ttf but no success.

Comment: you are on Windows so your path is :  D:\\web_projects\\test\\myfont.ttf

Comment: Used path as suggested but no luck. If the path is incorrect it does throw error.